# Защита от DDoS

Tags: ddos, debian

Есть VPS. ОС - Debian 5. Всё что на нём стоит - форум phpBB. Какие-то гады ддосят всё время. Ботнет - примерно 1500 компов. При чём с каждым разом всё больше извращаются, придумывают новые способы. Сейчас - ддосят пост и гет-запросами, компы по всему миру. Ид клиента - всё время разные. Поставил mod_evasive, mod_qos, DDoS-deflate, и ещё чё-то с GeoIP замутил, по статье в сети. В общем ничего не помогает. Всё зависает так сильно, что не могу даже апач остановить. Cannot allocate memory всякие выскакивают. Что делать? Неужели нет никакого способа? Это уже продолжается примерно четыре месяца, почти каждый день.

Comment: есть проф. защита от ddos. обычно предоставляется специализированными сервисами. многие хостеры предоставляют бесплатно.

Answer (score 4):

если есть доступ к **iptables**, то можно блокировать слишком активных юзеров этой утилитой, или реально обратиться за помощью, дополняю список выше - http://ddosoff.ru/ (нормальные ребята, все сделали быстро)

На самом деле, необходим комплекс мер, которые необходимо принять, чтобы отсечь нежелательные запросы и забанить ботнетовские IP-адреса. Ну а в iptables можно попробовать создать следующие правила:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "GET" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

Далее можно поставить ограничение по количеству одновременных соединений

```
# Лимит на 20 запросов в секунду для интерфейса eth0
/sbin/iptables --new-chain lim1
/sbin/iptables --insert OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -o eth0 --jump lim1
/sbin/iptables --append lim1-m limit --limit 20/sec --jump RETURN
/sbin/iptables --append lim1--jump DROP

# Максимум 10 одновременных соединений с одного IP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT-p tcp --dport 80 -m iplimit --iplimit-above 10 -j REJECT

# Блокировка более 10 SYN
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -j DROP -m iplimit --iplimit-above 10

# 20 соединений на сеть класса С
/sbin/iptables -p tcp --dport 80 -m iplimit --iplimit-above 20 --iplimit-mask 24 -j REJECT
```

А почитать про это все дело можно [здесь](http://bkmz.org/425/zashtita-ot-ddos-iptables), [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/infosecurity/84172/) и [здесь (бан по странам в debian)](http://debian.pro/510).

Comment: Да, есть доступ. Можете объяснить поподробнее?

Comment: КСТАТИ! Всех с Днем Программиста! :) *Биру-Бир!

Comment: стоит iptables v 1.4.2. iplimitа в нём нету. Вот вместо него пишу conntimil. Отвечает: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Comment: может все-таки connlimit ?

Comment: попробуй для начала забанить по стране (GeoIP)

Answer (score 0):

Если сами уже устали, то как минимум пара компаний:

- [ddosexpert.ru](http://www.ddosexpert.ru/)
- [tison.ru](http://www.tison.ru/)

возьмутся бесплатно отфильтровать вам до 100 Мб/с. Попробуйте, тоже вариант все-таки.

Comment: Устал. Очень. То есть, я так понимаю, с помощью модулей и\или скриптов отбить эти атаки не вариант никак?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Вы уже начали правильно, надо продолжать дальше. Но волшебного средства нет, верно? то есть я не могу ткнуть пальцем в конкретный модуль или еще что, и сказать, что после его установки все проблемы исчезнут.

Answer (score 0):

Используй услуги от ддос атак firewall.foxy.pro

Answer (score 0):

При удачной настройке `iptables nginx` попросту блокирует атакующие адреса и они не нагружают системные ресурсы сервера, а для решения серьезных проблем нужная хорошая аппаратная защита. Могу порекомендовать ребят из `Simplyway.net`, отлично справляются как с ддос атаками так и в администрировании.

Answer (score -2):

[ANTI DDOS. ЗАЩИТА ОТ DDOS](http://dd0s.blogspot.com/) - интересный блог.

Comment: Не прокатит 100%